# Email template netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have really big problem, i mean im working in a company where we are using NetSuite as our business platform and now they updated our account with new APIs.

Developer before me wrote this code

```
for(var k = 0; k < ResultsPPCI.length; k++){

    EmployeePPCI = ResultsPPCI[k].getValue('internalid'); //get the value
    // log('Internal ID', EmployeePPCI);

    // Merge, send, and associate an email with Purchase Order record (id=1000)
    var mergeValuesPPCI = {};
    mergeValuesPPCI.NLEMPFIRST = nlapiLookupField('employee', EmployeePPCI, 'firstname');
    mergeValuesPPCI.NLEMPLAST = nlapiLookupField('employee', EmployeePPCI, 'lastname');
    mergeValuesPPCI.NLSUPPLIER = nlapiLookupField('customer', cust, 'companyname');
    mergeValuesPPCI.NLPRODUCTCODE = productcodehtml;

    var emailBodyPPCI = nlapiMergeRecord(65, 'purchaseorder', poID, null, null, mergeValuesPPCI);
    var recordsPPCI = {};
    recordsPPCI['transaction'] = poID;

    nlapiSendEmail(EmployeePPCI, EmployeePPCI, emailBodyPPCI.getName(), emailBodyPPCI.getValue(), null, null, recordsPPCI);
    // log('EmployeePPCI',EmployeePPCI);
    nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', 'Potentional Problem', 'Email Sent');
}
```

I have problem now because `nlapiMergeRecord` is deprecated and it wont work. But i really cant find any working example online for hours... The most important part here is actually body of this email that has to be sent. In this case it is `productcodehtml` or `mergeValuesPPCI.NLPRODUCTCODE`.

This is how my template looks like :

```
<p>The QA Release has been submitted by <nlsupplier> for ${transaction.tranId}.</nlsupplier></p>

<p>The following item(s) have a short shelf life:</p>
<nlproductcode></nlproductcode>
```

Please can you help me with converting this code to new method? How can i connect `nlproductcode` from template with `mergeValuesPPCI.NLPRODUCTCOD` from my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kotnMergeTemplate](https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite) as a drop in replacement for nlapiMergeRecord

e.g.:

```
kotnMergeTemplate(65, 'purchaseorder', poID, null, null, mergeValuesPPCI);
```

the nlobjEmailMerger does not take custom values so you'd have to post process the results. Again you can look at the example in my script where you'd get the merged string and then run:

```
        var oldCustFieldPatt = /<(nl[^ >]+)>(\s*<\/\1>)?/ig;
        content = content.replace(oldCustFieldPatt, function(a,m){
            return mergeValuesPPCI[m.toUpperCase()] || mergeValuesPPCI[m.toLowerCase()] || '';
        });
```

Comment: Is there any native way? Without using 3rd part libraries?

Comment: The library is open source and is your quickest way to solve the issue. 
Otherwise check out nlapiCreateEmailMerger or nlapiCreateTemplateRenderer

Comment: how can i use this kotnMergeTemplate? how can i add it to my script?

Comment: download it and add it to your SuiteScripts folder. Then in your script definition add it as a library. Then in your script file change instances of nlapiMergeRecord to kotnMergeTemplate

Comment: Can you please just explain me how can i convert this object `mergeValuesPPCI ` from my code to record so i can load it on template? Im using `nlapiCreateEmailMerger` now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123025/discussion-between-aleksandar-dokic-and-bknights).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId)`

First you need to create your email template in netsuite and get the internal id.
Then:

1. Use nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId) to create an nlobjEmailMerger object.

   > var emailMerger = nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId);
2. Use the nlobjEmailMerger.merge() method to perform the mail merge.

   > var mergeResult = emailMerger.merge();
3. Use the nlobjMergeResult methods to obtain the e-mail distribution’s subject and body in string format.

   > var emailBody = mergeResult.getBody();
4. Send your email

   > nlapiSendEmail(senderInternalId, 'receiver@email.com','subject',emailBody, null, null, null);

Good luck!